# renamed files when I upload to a server

Tags: linux, file-upload, upload, ftp, file-rename

Recently i had a problem I'm uploading `PHP` to different servers but sometimes server change the name of some images or files and obviously that breaks so I have to check carefully if everything is ok.

Is there a way to avoid this and this happens only with some files there's not a patrol some one has an idea why this happens?

Example1:

`<a onClick="presstab2( )"><div id="aobutton4" style= "background-image: url(imgs/offline_activity/1/tabs/TEXTDesarrollo.png); height: 20px; width: 96px;"></div></a>`

the original image name is TEXTDesarrollo.png 
but when i check file uploaded to the server the name has changed to TextDesarrollo.png

Example2:

`<div id="wint" style= "background-image: url(imgs/offline_activity/1/Fondo.jpg); height: 648px; width: 996px;  border: 1px solid black;">`

the original image name is Fondo.jpg

but when i check file uploaded to the server the name has changed to fondo.png

I use filezilla for uploading and I had nevever has this problem before any advice to avoid this ?

Comment: Slow down, write sentences.  What is "patrol"?

Comment: Could you please post an example of renaming. The original name and the renamed name on the server?

Comment: Example1:

`<a onClick="presstab2( )"><div id="aobutton4" style= "background-image: url(imgs/offline_activity/1/tabs/TEXTDesarrollo.png); height: 20px; width: 96px;"></div></a>`

the original image name is TEXTDesarrollo.png 
but when i check file uploaded to the server the name has changed to TextDesarrollo.png

Example2:

`<div id="wint" style= "background-image: url(imgs/offline_activity/1/Fondo.jpg); height: 648px; width: 996px;  border: 1px solid black;">`

the original image name is Fondo.jpg 

but when i check file uploaded to the server the name has changed to fondo.png

Comment: "sometimes server change the name of some images or files" That... shouldn't happen at all. There's something wrong with your setup, your tools, or your server. A server does not rename files, and much less would replace a jpg with a png.

Comment: and what if I have no access to some servers to check this i mean I should use only minus letters ? that's the only solution I find by now